# Geocoding Requests problem?

Tags: android, http, geocoding

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/
I learned from here sending a request. 
First time when I am sending request it's fine I am receiving the responce. But when I am sending the second requst the reponce is "REQUEST_DENIED" indicates that your request was denied, generally because of lack of a sensor parameter. What's that mean? 
Is there any way that I can send requests and receive all responses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you develop for Android you should take a look at [`GeoCoder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class. It presumably uses the same background service, but it's all nicely packed, so you do not need to bother with details.

One note: this is only available if the device is a "Google" device, i.e. if it has Market on it: [Why is Android Geocoder throwing a "Service not Available" exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761052/why-is-android-geocoder-throwing-a-service-not-available-exception)