# Geocoder works in 1.6 but not in 2.2 emulator

Tags: android, dictionary, android-maps

`getFromLocationName()` alsways throws a `NullPointerException` in the Android 2.2 emulator but it's working fine in the Android 1.6 emulator.

This is my code snippet:

```
Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(GeocoderAppActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());     

try {       
    List<Address> add = geo.getFromLocationName("Tagore Road,Rajkot", 1);
    while (add.size() == 0) {
        Log.e("Girish", "in while");
        add = geo.getFromLocationName("Tagore Road,Rajkot", 1);
    }
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the emulator, are you using the regular `Android 2.2`, or the `Google Apis [Android 2.2]` version?

If you use the regular Android 2.2 one, it won't work. As far as I know it does not have the functionality to fulfill your actions. 
Open your SDK manager and download the Google Apis [Android 2.2] and create an AVD with that. Then try again, it should work.

Comment: ya i know that i am using google api 2.2 and tested in google api 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug which they never fixed see [service not available](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816) I think you will find that it works in the the API level 7 emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a Bug but I think it shall run on device.

Comment: have  u tested this in android 2.2 real device?

Comment: Check This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761052/why-is-android-geocoder-throwing-a-service-not-available-exception