# Does geocoder.getFromLocationName not work on emulators?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, google-geocoder

I am working on an app that takes the user input and then center the map on what the user entered.  I have properly installed the google maps API.  The map shows up. I also made sure the emulator is google API.  I have tested my code and the geocoder.getFromLocationName returns null.  I have looked up this questions and have tried different solutions and none have worked.  Here is my code.

```
 public class GetURL extends MapActivity {
Geocoder geocoder;
MapView mapView = null;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

       mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.geoMap);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


           int lat = (int)(30.334954*1000000);
            int lng = (int)(-81.5625*1000000);
        GeoPoint pt = new GeoPoint(lat,lng);
        mapView.getController().setZoom(10);
        mapView.getController().setCenter(pt);
        mapView.getController().animateTo(pt);

        geocoder = new Geocoder(this);

}

public void first_location(View arg0) {
    try {
          EditText loc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.location);
            String locationName = loc.getText().toString();

            List<Address> addressList = 
                   geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName, 5);
            if(addressList!=null && addressList.size()>0)
            {

                int lat = (int)(addressList.get(0).getLatitude()*1000000);
                int lng = (int)(addressList.get(0).getLongitude()*1000000);

                GeoPoint pt = new GeoPoint(lat,lng);
                mapView.getController().setZoom(15);
                mapView.getController().setCenter(pt);
                mapView.getController().animateTo(pt);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

If your app works on a real device, then your code should be fine. Think of geocoding as a service that companies have to subscribe or buy in to for their devices. I think most of them just use Google, but they could probably use Bing or some other as well.

From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html):

> The Geocoder class requires a backend service that is not included in
>   the core android framework. The Geocoder query methods will return an
>   empty list if there no backend service in the platform. Use the
>   isPresent() method to determine whether a Geocoder implementation
>   exists.

In my experience, calling `geocoder.isPresent()` from the emulator will return false, and from a real phone will return true, as long as the real phone is made by a company you've heard of.

If you want a work around/backup service, you can query the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) through HTTP just like you would from a web page. There's an example in this answer [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816#c21).

Answer (score 0):

What API version are you testing on? There appears to be a bug in earlier Android versions
[Geocoder works in 1.6 but not in 2.2 emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503693/geocoder-works-in-1-6-but-not-in-2-2-emulator)

Also make sure your app has INTERNET permission (I assume it does as your map shows map tiles)

I always use real devices to test location functionality as I find it much easier, and closer to real-world scenarios.

Do note that the geocoder functionality is only available on official Android devices, i.e. those with Market/Gmail/Maps etc. So a low-cost Android device without the Android Market will fail to provide geocode results.