# How to switch off Geocoder or NetworkLocator

Tags: android, geocoding

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110528/service-not-available-while-calling-geocoder-getfromlocation) question:

**Service not available while calling geoCoder.getFromLocation()**

And later found out that:

**NetworkLocator was killed on the device and Re-boot will resolve it**.

This is done and now everything is working.

The problem is I couldn't reproduce the same case. Is there a way to switch off this `Geocoder` service or `kill NetworkLocator`.

Because I did a work around to resolve this, and I want to test it.

Thank You

Comment: You can use any root process manager App to terminate system processes.

Comment: eww. No other(simpler) way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just force closed

> Google Play Services

from apps.

Answer (score 0):

use this trick.

simply edit the project.properties

```
# Project target
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:16
```

The reason is that the Geocoder class is present in the core Android framework, but depends on code contributed by the Google APIs to function properly. Even if your AVD includes the Google APIs, your project still needs to be built against that specific build target.