# Geocoder doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-activity, geocoding, street-address

I have a problem with `Geocoder`. I have done some research but i didn't find an answer to my problem.

This is my code:

```
public String getAddress(double lat,double lon){

 TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
 TextView tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);

  tv.setText(lat+","+lon);///Checks did i received lat and lon (Yes)
  String ret = "";
  try {
      Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this.getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
      List<Address>addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);
      if (addresses.isEmpty()) {
          ret = "No Address returned!";
      } else {
          ret = addresses.get(0).getCountryName() + ""+ >addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
      }
  } catch (IOException e) {
      ret="We don't know your address...";
      e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return ret;
}
```

I tried to run my app on the emulator and my phone but it doesn't work. Every time it tells me `"We don't know..."`

I have permissions for `INTERNET, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.`

Comment: Have you check in the logcat if there is some warnings related to this?

Comment: if the device api level is less than jellybean then you might need to reboot the device http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110528/service-not-available-while-calling-geocoder-getfromlocation

Comment: Could you post the stack trace from the IOException that is thrown?

Comment: E/sw29 TextView(11517): getCurrentProcessName currProcessID=11517 , E/sw29 TextView(11517): currProcessName=com.rServices.home

Comment: thx , problem is solved! When i rebooted it work very good. thx :)