# Geocoder returns empty list on real device

Tags: android, locationmanager

I'm trying to get the country name using NETWORK_PROVIDER, i wrote a method

```
private int getCurrentLocation(Location location) throws IOException {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, getResources().getConfiguration().locale);
    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 5);

    String CurrentCountryFullName = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
    if (CurrentCountryFullName != null) {
        for (StandartCurrency standartCurrency: RecourcesForStandartCurrencies.getStandartCurrencyList()){
            if (RecourcesForStandartCurrencies.getCountryFullName(standartCurrency.getPosition()).toLowerCase().contains(CurrentCountryFullName.toLowerCase()))
                return standartCurrency.getPosition();
        }
    }
    return AddedCurrency.getAddedCurrenciesCount();
}
```

I call this method from

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    try {
        leftFieldIndex = getCurrentLocation(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
```

My AdnroidManifest.xml contains

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

I'm testing on Nexus 4, it has wifi connection with working internet, but still not working.

Comment: your sure location you passing to geocoder call is valid?, its not null right? coz location manager will return null if last know location is not available, this this case geocoder will fail.

Comment: instead of gocoder use, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/ this gives you result all the time.

Comment: Techfist, yes, i'm sure, i get coordinates with debugger and put them into google maps, and they were right.

Comment: alright, its better you use geocoding api which i posted above, that baby is stable and always returns valid results.

Answer (score 7):

`Geocoder` is not stable and sometimes stops working. You have not posted an error log or exception but from experience, when `Geocoder` breaks it simply returns an empty list. Unfortunately there is no way to check if `Geocoder` is working in advance (there is only a method to check if `Geocoder` is available, which will return true even if it is not functioning)

The work around is to connect to the Google Maps web api when your `Geocoder` returns an empty list. Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110528/service-not-available-while-calling-geocoder-getfromlocation) for an example of the code. You're pretty much going to just check to see if the list returned from the `Geocoder` is null or empty first and if it is use an `AsyncTask` to make a web api call to the Google Maps api. The end result is the same so you should not notice a difference in functionality.

```
private int getCurrentLocation(Location location) throws IOException {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, getResources().getConfiguration().locale);
    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),   location.getLongitude(), 5);
    if(addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0 {
        //use addresses
    } else {
        //call web API async task 
    }

}
```

Depending on what you're doing with the addresses, it may make sense to break out your `Geocoder` implementation into a separate class. That way you can use an `Interface` to connect your `Geocoder` class to your activity or fragment and make a seamless transition between your `AsyncTask` web api call and `Geocoder` should the later stop working (you obviously cannot return the results of the `AsyncTask` in the same method because it is not delivered at the time the method is finished)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I switched to v3 web API.
Now I'm using [the java client](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/client-library) and all work well.

All info are in the [Google Maps page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/)