# Geocoder isPresent() fails in android geocoder

Tags: android, google-geocoder

### I am using GeoCoder in android

- I  am using `isPresent()` to check whether the `GeoCoder` service is
  running in the application

---

### Logic:

```
if(GeoCoderObject.isPresent()){
 Log.d("Message","GeoCoder instance is there");
 try{
  someMethod();
}
catch(IOException){
 Log.d("Message","Wiered Scenario");
}
catch(Esception e){
 Log.d("Message","Geocoder service not available");
}
}else{
 Log.d("Message","GeoCoder instance is not there");
}
```

---

### Exception raised:

```
java.io.IOException: Service not Available
```

### Log displayed in output is:

- Wiered Scenario

[*This is a similar behaviour as seen in another answer of stackoverflow here*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15110651/1083093)

---

### Question:

- *Well I can catch that perticular exception and make a new implementation if it is raised but is there any methods to check for
  this scenario !*

***Note:*** this isPresent() was working perfectly with device yesterday. today it is raising this error (no code changes was done)

Comment: When the geocoder is not present and if you restart the device, geocoder restarts too and will be present. I had same issue, not sure why and how :( hoping someone gives us a solid solution.