# android Geocoder throws IOException: Service not Available

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoder

after removing firebase analytics, ads and crashlytics (and google-services.json), I get the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Service not Available
```

Code:

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
final List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latlng.latitude, latlng.longitude, 1);
```

I don't find any explanation why this happens... Anyone here who can help me?
There is no APIKey to appy or something, right?

PS: My maps fragment is working (com.google.android.geo.API_KEY meta-data in manifest is used)

I'm running OnePlus One, Android 8.1.0 (aosp_bacon-8.1.0-20180331.agentfabulous) and gapps mini.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Android Geocoder throwing a "Service not Available" exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761052/why-is-android-geocoder-throwing-a-service-not-available-exception)

Comment: Oh, I recently reinstalled my Phone and thats maybe the problem... Uuuuh. I should test it with another phone (That I don't have :( ). However, I have Google Play and all this stuff installed, of course...

Comment: As the following answer suggest that RESTART YOUR PHONE will fix the problem. Check out this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36956130)

Comment: doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with my phone. I will implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110528/service-not-available-while-calling-geocoder-getfromlocation).
I'm going to close this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Yes u need geocoding api key:
When i used have same problem my solution was restart phone but from reserch then i found couple solution about that.
Recreate api key
Api key get limit or bugeed
Use other for check is it blame of full service or not
Move one part to other project and check does it work if yes that meen it's problem in code somew here

Comment: But where to put the API Key? Since I deleted the google-services.json. And I don't want to re-create this file, because I deleted the firebase project...

Comment: I am not sure but if i good remember i wrote it in Manifest as metadata something like that 

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="key" />

app\src\main\res\values also here had file i just checked

Comment: Thats what I've done. This works for my Google Maps Fragment, but not for my Geocoder...

Comment: is that so meybe your key just expired orbugged it's posible your app work becouse app wasn't uninstalled

Comment: I reinstalled the app and the map still works. Strange... But not the geocoder... I think I will try with a temporary new key...

Comment: try also turn on and off phone when i wrote my enginery work i spend alot of time to figure it out

Comment: Yeah, I did this at least 10 times until I have the problem :p