# Flutter geolocator plugin Geolocator().placemarkFromAddress() and Geolocator().placemarkFromCoordinates() do not work

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation

I am trying to search an address and then trying to get position of that location by Geolocator and then trying to set camera position to this position but it does not work.

I find out some exceptions for two methods of Geolocator. All others methods of Geolodator work fine for me:

**1. Geolocator().placemarkFromAddress() shows:**

> PlatformException(ERROR_GEOCODING_ADDRESS, Service not Available, null)

**2. Geolocator().placemarkFromCoordinates() shows:**

> PlatformException(ERROR_GEOCODING_COORDINATES, Service not Available, null)

**Here Code that I am trying:**

```
try {
  List<Placemark> placemark = await Geolocator().placemarkFromAddress(searchAddress);
  Placemark newPlace = placemark[0];
  controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(
     target: LatLng(newPlace.position.latitude,newPlace.position.longitude),
     zoom: 15.0,
  )));
}catch(e){
   print(e);
}
```

Comment: Are you connected to the internet on your testing device ?

Comment: yes. I am running this app in real device and internet connection was available. All others methods of geolocator works fine.

Comment: Maybe some problem with your ISP or country you are working from because in my demo project this is just working fine (Austria)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

placemarkFromCoordinates has been moved from plugin  `geolocator`  to  `geocoding` , just add plugin [`geocoding`](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding)  in `pubspec.yaml` and user placemarkFromCoordinates

Answer (score 1):

I find out the solution for this question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110528/service-not-available-while-calling-geocoder-getfromlocation?fbclid=IwAR13V1tcMSgTxJfWFap5u5BNHhs12JMqmfxVOxuirIhPZvlGLWzz0dlQbac).

I Just reload my phone/device it works fine for me.

[Tap here for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110528/service-not-available-while-calling-geocoder-getfromlocation?fbclid=IwAR13V1tcMSgTxJfWFap5u5BNHhs12JMqmfxVOxuirIhPZvlGLWzz0dlQbac)

Answer (score 1):

Its now moved to https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';

class MapScreen02 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapScreen02State createState() => _MapScreen02State();
}

class _MapScreen02State extends State<MapScreen02> {
  GoogleMapController mapController;
  String searchAdd;
  // List<Location> locations = await locationFromAddress("Gronausestraat 710, Enschede");
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          GoogleMap(
            onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
            initialCameraPosition:
                CameraPosition(target: LatLng(40.7128, -74.0060), zoom: 10.0),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 30,
            right: 15,
            left: 15,
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Enter Address',
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 15,
                    top: 15,
                  ),
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                    onPressed: searchnavigate,
                    iconSize: 30,
                  ),
                ),
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    searchAdd = val;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  searchnavigate() {
    locationFromAddress(searchAdd).then((result) {
      mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(result[0].latitude, result[0].longitude),
        zoom: 10,
      )));
    });
  }

  void onMapCreated(controller) {
    setState(() {
      mapController = controller;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [GeoCoding](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding) package instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the geoCoding plugin and use it like this:

```
List<Placemark> placemark = await placemarkFromCoordinates(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude);
```