# Android - Google Map V2 - LOCATION_SERVICE not available on device error

Tags: android, google-maps, service, location

i created a project that uses google map v2 and sdk 21 , i want to show address of a marker point in text view , i used Geocoder class and getFromLocation method to get address , on device has error "service not available" , etc: i activated location service on my phone
then do you know what's the problem

Comment: can you elaborate more? @Nasrin

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761052/why-is-android-geocoder-throwing-a-service-not-available-exception/4762815#4762815) answer.