# Android Geocoder issue

Tags: android, android-location, google-geocoder

I am new in Android. I develop one application which have to display Current Location name. I tried to use Geocoder class. But it seems in some phone display properly Location but in some it is displaying any location and getting null.

My code is here,

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> listAddresses = null;
    try {
        listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude(), 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (null != listAddresses && listAddresses.size() > 0) {
        Location = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (listAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) != null) {
                Location += listAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + ",";
            }
        }
        Log.e("Location", Location);
    }
```

My Manifest class,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

I can't understand what is the problem ? Is it depend on different devices ? Or any other reason ?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761052/why-is-android-geocoder-throwing-a-service-not-available-exception

Comment: can you check if you are getting current location latitude and longitude or not and any error or exception in logs ?

Comment: yes i get lat and long proper..

Answer (score 0):

```
    **Just pass your current lat-long in this method and you will get address:**    

private void getAddress(double locationLatitude, double locationLongitude) {
                Geocoder gCoder = new Geocoder(getActivity());
                try {
                    final List<Address> list = gCoder.getFromLocation(locationLatitude, locationLongitude, 1);
                    if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
                        Address address = list.get(0);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        if (address.getAddressLine(0) != null) {
                            sb.append(address.getAddressLine(0)).append("\n");
                        }
                        sb.append(address.getLocality()).append(",");
                        // sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append(",");
                        sb.append(address.getCountryName());
                        strAddress = sb.toString();
                        strAddress = strAddress.replace(",null", "");
                        strAddress = strAddress.replace("null", "");
                        strAddress = strAddress.replace("Unnamed", "");
                    }
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(strAddress)) {
                                Logg.e("address++++", "" + strAddress);
                                edtZipcode.setFocusable(false);
                                edtZipcode.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                                edtZipcode.setText(strAddress); // set your current address in this edittext using your current lat-long
                                edtZipcode.setFocusable(true);
                                edtZipcode.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                            } else {
                                Logg.e("address", "");
                                edtZipcode.setText("");
                                Toast.show(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.toast_enter_zipcode));
                                new Animation(Techniques.Shake, 1000, edtZipcode);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                } catch (IOException exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a intent service first for getting a location address.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.google.android.gms.location.sample.locationaddress" >
<application
    ...
    <service
        android:name=".FetchAddressIntentService"
        android:exported="false"/>
</application>
...
```

Then extends your class with **IntentService** to use onHandle

```
 @Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
String errorMessage = "";

// Get the location passed to this service through an extra.
Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(
        Constants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA);

...

List<Address> addresses = null;

try {
    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
            location.getLatitude(),
            location.getLongitude(),
            // In this sample, get just a single address.
            1);
} catch (IOException ioException) {
    // Catch network or other I/O problems.
    errorMessage = getString(R.string.service_not_available);
    Log.e(TAG, errorMessage, ioException);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException) {
    // Catch invalid latitude or longitude values.
    errorMessage = getString(R.string.invalid_lat_long_used);
    Log.e(TAG, errorMessage + ". " +
            "Latitude = " + location.getLatitude() +
            ", Longitude = " +
            location.getLongitude(), illegalArgumentException);
}

// Handle case where no address was found.
if (addresses == null || addresses.size()  == 0) {
    if (errorMessage.isEmpty()) {
        errorMessage = getString(R.string.no_address_found);
        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
    }
    deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.FAILURE_RESULT, errorMessage);
} else {
    Address address = addresses.get(0);
    ArrayList<String> addressFragments = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Fetch the address lines using getAddressLine,
    // join them, and send them to the thread.
    for(int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
        addressFragments.add(address.getAddressLine(i));
    }
    Log.i(TAG, getString(R.string.address_found));
    deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.SUCCESS_RESULT,
            TextUtils.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"),
                    addressFragments));
}
  }
```

For more clarification you can use following link too

[Developer Android](http://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html)

[Github Sample Project](https://github.com/punitsharma/AndroidLocationFused)