# Is Android Geocoder using Google's Geocoding API?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I'm using this [Android Geocoder class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder) and I was wondering if this is using the Google Geocoding API behind the scenes.

This is what the documentation says:

> The Geocoder class requires a backend service that is not included in the core android framework.The Geocoder query methods will return an empty list if there no backend service in the platform.

So I'm not sure what kind of backend service is running but it works for me. Maybe it uses Google Play Services?

In case this Geocoder class is using the Geocoder API from Google.. does this mean:

1. I need to [display attribution](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/policies) on the search results?
2. I'll be charged by requests according to [their pricing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761052/why-is-android-geocoder-throwing-a-service-not-available-exception it uses Play Services. I don't think you need to worry about either of your points.